# Unified Testing Environment for Windows, iOS, Android and MacOS

Tags: mobile, desktop-application, virtualmachine

We are developing a program to download apps/software on devices and configure device settings, across the four main OS's. We're looking for a repeatable way to test our deployment virtually but not aware of something that facilitates this.

We're aware of things like Appium, VirtualBox, SauceLabs, BrowserStack, etc. but don't think these are able to do all four operating systems (please correct me if I'm wrong). Many focus on browser compatibility testing but we need just the raw OS to test the remote deployment of our automation.

We can obviously use a VM and manually load MacOS and Windows, but not sure this is possible for Android and iOS?

Any suggestions welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manual testing all you will need is a Mac. For Windows run a VM, for Android run an AVD in Android Studio, and for iOS use a Simulator in XCode.

There is a line out the door to sell you a "unified solution" for automation and recommending one would be opinion based.

Comment: Thanks so much!