# Cloud Based Cross Platform Testing Environment?

Tags: test-management, test-automation-framework

Previously asked this question around testing environments for Windows, MacOS, Android and iOS;

[Unified Testing Environment for Windows, iOS, Android and MacOS](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45369/unified-testing-environment-for-windows-ios-android-and-macos)

The answer "For Windows run a VM, for Android run an AVD in Android Studio, and for iOS use a Simulator in XCode." is a good solution but is local to a device.

Is anyone aware of an approach or solution whereby our testing can be cloud based? i.e. different members of the team can test our product on each OS from a central testing platform (that doesn't have to sit locally on each persons machine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael suggestions are pretty nice, but maybe also have a look at the AWS Device Lab: https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/ and its alternatives https://www.g2.com/products/aws-device-farm/competitors/alternatives

The regular operating systems can be installed in most Clouds. Only for macOs you need to find another provider, for example https://www.macincloud.com/

Comment: +1 Niels always has good suggestions :)

Comment: Thanks guys, really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes browserstack and Sauce Labs are long standing and leading providers of cloud based browsers and emulators.

- https://www.browserstack.com/
- https://saucelabs.com/

They include options for connecting to your local environment so you can test your system without needing to upload or create a testing system.  This meets the need of "your system but with multiple browsers and devices"

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking for a cloud-based ecosystem, you can try [LambdaTest](https://www.lambdatest.com/) - a cross-browser testing tool. It avoids the need to maintain an in-house architecture by offering a flexible online testing cloud.

LambdaTest provides you with an [online Selenium Grid](https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation) that enables you to run both manual and automated software tests of your websites and web apps over 2,000+ different browsers, browser versions, and operating systems environments such as  Windows, macOS, Android, and iOS.

Comment: Thanks Salman, does it give you access to the menu options for the respective OS's? i.e. would we be able to browse through the latest OS settings menu's for each operating system?

Comment: Hey Jonny, yes you can perform web-based testing on all browsers and OS combinations. Here is the list of browsers and operating systems supported by LambdaTest >>> https://www.lambdatest.com/list-of-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Cloud-based cross-platform testing can be beneficial when you need different teams from different locations to test the same project. Some of the few good tools which I think could help you have the advantage of the cloud with your test initiatives can be

- SOASTA CloudTest
- Load Storm
- Blaze Meter
- Jenkins Dev@Cloud
- Xamarin test cloud

All these options are good to ensure that your testers could enjoy the cloud environment for testing without much struggle on understanding the tools.